# What is the full parameters list for SerDeInfo in aws glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_SerDeInfo.html) is a link to description `SerDeInfo` parameter. They defined `parameters` as map, but what key and value they expect? There are some examples like:

```
"SerdeInfo": {
  "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde",
  "Parameters": {
    "field.delim": ",",
    "serialization.format": "1"
  }
},
```

But what full list is?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Apache Hive documents for the details of each type of Serializer/Deserializer. E.g. for the OpenCSVSerde:

https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/OpenCSVSerde.html

Based on my rudimentary understanding of Java, I think you can set four parameters:

- LOG
- SEPARATORCHAR
- QUOTECHAR
- ESCAPECHAR

From the [AWS docs for Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html) we have this tip:

> Enter appropriate values for separatorChar, quoteChar, and escapeChar. The separatorChar value is a comma (,), the quoteChar value is double quotes ("), and the escapeChar value is the backslash (\).

So it appears that you are supposed to use `lowerCamelCase` versions of the Java fields. Although I've never seen that convention documented in Glue docs.

Comment: Same info, but on a different location. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde & https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html